# Airflow logs are empty in UI

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, airflow-webserver, kubernetesexecutor

I have a DAG that ran for 2 hours but I can not see any log in the UI.
In addition, I can't see how many attempts there were (or if there were any at all).

In the airflow webserver pod (where the UI runs), I can see some logs, but they are not relevant and I can not find any that can indicate a problem.

In the airflow scheduler the only line that looks weird is this line:

```
[34mkubernetes_executor.py:[0m469} INFO[0m - Found 0 queued task instances[0m
```

1. Why there are no logs in the UI?
2. Does it mean that they do not exist or do they exist somewhere (where?!) and the UI does not show them?
3. Let's say that there are no logs at all, where do i should search the root cause?

[image]